# Multiple Object Mutation in Ruby GraphQL with GraphQLList

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I have a Rails API application with GraphQL. I'm currently trying to create a Mutation to update several objects at once.

```
module Mutations
  module Widgets
    class UpdateWidgets < ::Mutations::BaseMutation
      argument :widgets, [Types::WidgetType, null: true], required: true

      field :widgets, [Types::WidgetType], null: true
      field :errors,  [String], null: true

      def resolve(widgets:)
        # update widgets here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
GraphQL::Schema::InvalidTypeError:
     Argument input on Mutation.updateWidgets is invalid: argument "widgets" type must be a valid input type (Scalar or InputObject), not GraphQL::ListType ([Widget!])
```

I then heard the suggestion to make it an Input Object, and I did the following:

```
module Types
  class UpdateWidgetsType < Types::BaseInputObject
    description 'Input for multiple widgets'
    argument :widgets, [Types::WidgetType, null: true], required: true
  end
end
```

Now that it's an Input type I adjusted the mutation to call

`argument :update_widgets, Types::UpdateWidgetType, required: true`

instead and getting a similar error:

```
GraphQL::Schema::InvalidTypeError:
     Input field UpdateWidgetsInput.updateWidgets is invalid: argument "widgets" type must be a valid input type (Scalar or InputObject), not GraphQL::NonNullType ([Widget]!)
```

Looking for any insight on how to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine pushed me in the direction over Twitter. Ran some tests both manually and with RSpec and got it working.

The big issue was leaning too heavily on the Widget type instead of fully extracting it out:

```
# app/graphql/types/update_widget_type.rb
module Types
  class UpdateWidgetType < Types::BaseInputObject
    description 'Input for a Widget'

    argument :id, Int, required: true
    argument :name, String, required: false
    # and the rest
  end
end

# app/graphql/mutations/widgets/update_widgets.rb
module Mutations
  module Widgets
    class UpdateWidgets < ::Mutations::BaseMutation

      argument :update_widgets, [Types::UpdateWidgetType, null: true], required: true

      field :widgets, [Types::WidgetType], null: true
      field :errors, [String], null: false

      def resolve(update_widgets:)
        # update widgets here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The query would then look like this:

```
mutation {
  updateWidgets(input: {
    updateWidgets: [
      {
        id: 1
        name: "Foo"
      },
      {
        id: 2
        name: "Bar"
      }
    ]
  }
}) {
  widgets {
    id
    name
  }
}
```